# Applications of additive version of Hilbert's theorem 90

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

Additive version of Hilbert's theorem 90 says that whenever $k \subset F$ is cyclic Galois extension with Galois group generated by $g$,  and $a$ is element of $L$ with trace 0, there exists an element $b$ of $L$ such that $a = b - g(b)$.

The corresponding multiplicative version with norm instead of trace has many interesting applications, for instance determining Pythagorean triples, or solving Pell's equation. How about the additive version? Where it can be useful?

Answer (score 10):

An example that first comes to my mind deals with quadratic equations over a finite field $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ of characteristic two. There the additive Hilbert 90 says that
$$
x^2+x=a
$$
with $a\in \Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ has a solution (obviously then two solutions) in $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$, if and only if $tr(a)=0$. This reinterpretation comes from the following observations:

- Squaring, i.e. the Frobenius automorphism $F$, is a generator of the Galois group $Gal(\Bbb{F}_{2^n}/\Bbb{F}_2)$.
- $F(x)-x=x^2-x=x^2+x$ for all $x\in \Bbb{F}_{2^n}$.

This leads to solvability criteria of a general quadratic over $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$:
$$
x^2+bx+a=0\qquad(*)
$$
with $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ has solutions in $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$, iff $tr(a/b^2)=0$ -
divide $(*)$ by $b^2$, and write it in terms of the new variable $y=x/b$). Note that
the usual trick of completing the square is unavailable in characteristic two. Also note that $(*)$ has a double root in $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$, if $b=0$.

Admittedly this example is not very satisfying here, because:

- we can derive this result without knowing about Hilbert 90, and
- it's not about algebraic number fields.

Comment: I actually find it quite nice and interesting, so thank you for your response :) I'll
 be happy to hear if you have any other example.

Comment: Apart from the examples given above, you can apply additive Hilbert 90 to show (easily) that in an extension of finite fields, the trace map is surjective. But, as noticed by Jyrki, it is a curious fact that in the setting of CFT, i.e.  for number fields or function fields of positive chracteristic, the prominent role is played by the norm (hence multiplicative H. 90), not by the trace (additive H. 90) .

Answer (score 7):

Google Artin-Schreier theory, an additive analogue of Kummer theory. In particular, the proof of the Artin-Schreier theorem about non-algebraically closed fields whose algebraic closure is a finite extension is a beautiful application (when treating the case of fields with characteristic $p$).

Quite generally, these additive theorems are useful in characteristic $p$ when dealing with extensions of degree $p$ or more generally a power of $p$, depending on the situation. If you are not a fan of characteristic $p$ then the additive Hilbert Theorem 90 will not be your friend.