# How many elements in the finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb F_{q^{2n}}$ be a finite field, and let $a,b\sim\text{Unif}\lbrace 0,q^{2n}-1\rbrace$. What is the probability that:

> 1. $a - a^q\in\mathbb F_{q^2}$
> 2. $a - a^q = b - b^q$

Comment: Do not re-ask your questions if they don't get an answer. Edit to clarify them. Since this version has an answer, and the old one hadn't I have deleted the old version.

Comment: To make sure: the elements of $\Bbb{F}_{q^{2n}}$ are  not **naturally** in a bijective correspondence with the set of integers in the range $[0,q^{2n}-1]$. Presumably you are expected to use the uniform distribution of $\Bbb{F}_{q^{2n}}$ instead of the one on integers.

Answer (score 3):

The additive version of [Hilbert's theorem 90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_Theorem_90) tells you that the kernel of the trace $\mathbb{F}_{q^{2n}} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{q}$ consists precisely of the elements of the form $a - a^q$ with $a \in \mathbb{F}_{q^{2n}}.$ Likewise, the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ of the form $a - a^q$ are also precisely the traceless elements.

Since the trace is a nonzero functional, its kernel has order $q^{2n-1}$ (on $\mathbb{F}_{q^{2n}}$) and $q$ (on $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$). Combined with the linearity of the map $a \mapsto a - a^q$ this is enough to solve both problems.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with it, a [discussion of the additive version of Hilbert's Theorem 90](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639310/applications-of-additive-version-of-hilberts-theorem-90)

Comment: Sorry for late. What does "the traceless elements" mean?

Comment: @PiggyJin elements with $\mathrm{tr}(a) = 0$

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand. Could you explain again?

Comment: @PiggyJin You can argue directly that the kernel of $a \mapsto a^q$ is exactly $\mathbb{F}_q$ and count the image that way. The point is that $a - a^q$ is not just an arbitrary polynomial but a linear map, so everything reduces to linear algebra

Comment: What I understood : suppose that $a - a^q in \mathbb F_{q^2}$. then because of the Hilbert 90 Theorem, $a - a^q$ in the kernal of trace map from $\mathbb F_{q^2}$ to $\mathbb F_{q}$. Is that right? 
I think this is wrong, so I cannot understand the above argument.

Comment: Does the result depend on the characteristic of $\mathbb F_q$?