# Solving a quadratic equation in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

I'm learning finite fields.  The equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ can be solved in the reals trivially.  If $a, b, c, x$ are elements of a finite field, is there a procedure to solve it?

Comment: It depends upon the characteristic of the field.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you elaborate? I'm particularly interested in $GF(2^{4096})$, but would appreciate general explanation.

Comment: Then you are interested in working over a field whose characteristic is $2$. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2108572/446262).

Comment: For finite fields in particular there is more definitve theory than what is given in the thread José linked to. For me personally it has always at the level of a FAQ. The theory is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/639319/11619). I should probably add an explanation of the use of the so called half trace. Probably the thread José linked to is a good place to do that.